# Programmatically set-up ADFS SSO Session Cookie

Tags: adfs2.0

What's the best way to avoid your Relying Party Application from redirecting to ADFS login page for authentication?

I understand you can construct WSTrustChannelFactory to request a security token programmatically for your relying party application.

After this step is there a way to set-up ADFS SSO Session cookie as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way - for that a browser redirect is required.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Dominick! I'm trying to have a custom login page to improve the user experience while dealing with multiple AD/ADFS. I see you said there is no way to set the SSO session cookie, but is there any other way to   get the session cookie on behalf of the logged in user through a web request and persisting that session cookie?

Comment: You can only set your local cookie. ADFS is the only one who can set the ADFS SSO cookie.

Comment: Aww man! I really wish there is a way! Thanks for the response though!

Comment: if u have access to your adfs/ls website then you can customize it

Answer (score 0):

Only possible if you can change ADFS controller page. if you are planning to grab username and password from user and send it to ADFS, you are breaking trust principal